# Walmart MX Marketplace Acknowledge Order API Issue

Tags: php, curl, walmart-api

I am working on Walmart integration to my own web application using PHP. When I tried to acknowledge my Mexico orders, I got an empty response. The data type of response is string with 0 length, error code 400. It looks like my credentials are good. Is "https://marketplace.walmartapis.com/v3/orders/{PurchaseOrderId}/acknowledge" a valid API url?

```
$url="https://marketplace.walmartapis.com/v3/orders/P108915403/acknowledge";
$ch      = curl_init();
$qos     = uniqid();
$options = array(
    CURLOPT_URL            => $url,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 60,
    CURLOPT_HEADER         => false,
    CURLOPT_POST           =>1,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER     => array(
        "WM_SVC.NAME: Walmart Marketplace",
        "WM_QOS.CORRELATION_ID: $qos",
        "Authorization: Basic $authorization",
        "WM_SEC.ACCESS_TOKEN:$token",
        "Accept: application/json",
        "Content-Type: application/json",
        "WM_MARKET: mx",
    ),
);
curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
var_dump($response);
```

[Code Snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mu9JC.png)

Comment: I would have thought that was something you should have a better idea of than any of us

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After putting it aside for a few months, today I picked it up  and finally got it resolved luckily and got a 202 Accepted Response with empty content(Walmart's documentation says the response to a successful call contains the acknowledged order, but it actually contains nothing except for 202 Accepted code).

When I tried to acknowledge my Mexico orders, the response is actually not empty. The header contains error message: http code 400 Bad Request. I confirmed that it is due to wrong payload structure after testing.
So "https://marketplace.walmartapis.com/v3/orders/{PurchaseOrderId}/acknowledge" is a valid API URL and is the same as US API. The difference between them is that MX site needs a well-structured payload through POST while US site does not(US API only needs an empty payload through POST).

The key point to a successful call is the structure of the payload. The structure should be like the samples in the [documentation](https://developer.walmart.com/api/mx/mp/orders#operation/acknowledgeOrders).

Pay attention to the details of the structure. [Refer to the picture for the structure of payload here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tvDMg.png)
The **"orderLine"** and **"orderLineStatus"** should be declared as ARRAY instead of single element. And this is the reason why I failed to call the acknowledge API before.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you are using an old API, which has been discontinued, the same has been communicated late December 2020.

We have improved our onboarding experience with following steps:

1. Create an account on Walmart IO platform - https://walmart.io by clicking on the user icon just before the search box.
2. Login to the account and accept "Terms of Use"
3. Click on "Create Your Application" to create a new application and fill in appropriate details.
4. Use this tutorial to generate two sets of public/private keys - https://walmart.io/key-tutorial       
   * One set will be used for production.        
   * Other set will be used for stage.
5. Upload both public keys using - https://walmart.io/key-upload?app_name=<your app name>
6. Consumer ID will be generated for both sets for prod and stage which can be seen on the dashboard - https://walmart.io/userdashboard
7. Click on "Request Access" for Checkout APIs at https://walmart.io/reference  and fill out the form.
8. Once the access is approved, documentation will be available for integrating with Commerce API through Walmart I/O.
9. We will send out client secrets for stage and prod as soon as they’re ready.
    
   Thanks,
   Firdos
   IOSupport